# linux: drop fulltext from table using bash tools

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

How can I drop fulltext from sql file using bash tools?

I need to clone myisam table and covert it into INNODB, therefor i can't use

```
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON table_name
```

what i've tried

```
sed -i 's@FULLTEXT.*.)@@g' post.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky to automate for at least three reasons:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `c` TEXT,
  FULLTEXT KEY `c` (`c`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

- Removing the FULLTEXT KEY line would also require removing the comma on the end of the preceding line.  Or else replacing the FULLTEXT KEY line with some other line.
- The string "FULLTEXT KEY" might occur in your SQL script elsewhere, inside a string literal or in a comment.  So you have to be careful about false positive matches.
- We could simply change "FULLTEXT KEY" to "KEY" but it's fairly common for fulltext indexes to be declared on long VARCHAR or TEXT columns, which would be too long for the 1000-byte limit on a conventional index.  You could use index prefixes, but choosing the prefix length and handling multi-column indexes in regular expressions is hard.

I'd solve this problem by dropping all the FULLTEXT indexes *before* I create the SQL script.  You can query all FULLTEXT indexes and produce the drop statements from the information schema.
For example:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_schema, '`.`', table_name, '` DROP KEY `', 
  index_name, '`;') AS ddl 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS 
WHERE table_schema='test' and index_type='FULLTEXT';
```

My second choice, if you can't change the original database and you need to change the script, would be to *manually* edit the SQL script in a text editor, instead of trying to automate it.  That gives you the opportunity to inspect each case and edit it in the right way.

If your SQL script is a very large file, you may have to choose your text editor carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I automate this using a PHP snippet, but I am sure perl or sed can do this in a similar fashion. I surround the full text index in c-style comments so nothing is lost.

`php -r 'file_put_contents("schema.sql", preg_replace("/(,\s+FULLTEXT KEY [^)]+\))/", "/*$1*/", file_get_contents("schema.sql")));'`

This works against a MySQL schema file (CREATE TABLE).

As pointed out by Bill Karwin, if you run this against a full SQL dump that contained data which might match the regular expression, then it would modify that data.